# Как запустить python скрипт с другого url?

Tags: python, windows, cmd

Не понимаю, как в командной строке написать что-то в духе:

```
python https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Стандартная `python` программа не выполняет удалённые скрипты (только локальные пути можно указывать).

Есть модули, которые позволяют импортировать удалённый код, но это скорее игрушка, которую не следует использовать, если вы точно не знаете зачем вам это нужно.

`pip` по умолчанию уже включён в установку Питона, поэтому чтобы обновить `pip`, до новейшей версии, достаточно:

```
$ python -m pip install -U pip
```

В общем случае, чтобы запустить удалённый скрипт:

1. Скачайте его локально:

   ```
   $ python
   >>> from urllib.request import urlretrieve # assuming Python 3
   >>> urlretrieve('https://example.com/some-script.py', 'some-script.py')
   ```
2. Запустите:

   ```
   $ python some-script.py
   ```

Comment: О, тоже хорошо.
Только у меня Windows)

Comment: @flow: код работает везде где Питон работает.